# Apache Camel: update route through JMX throws org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM

Tags: weblogic, apache-camel, jmx, jconsole

A small component was developed upon Apache Camel to act as a multicaster, forwarding incoming messages to a set of endpoints.

This component is running on a WebLogic server.

Version details:

- JDK: 1.6 / 1.7.0_75
- Apache Camel:2.14.1
- WebLogic: 10.3.6

A new requirement came up to modify in runtime the set of destination endpoints without the need of rebuilding and redeploying the component.

The first idea was to use the JMX functionality provided by Apache Camel to achieve this.

JConsole is used as JMX Client.

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wlfullclient.jar;%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wljmxclient.jar -debug
```

As connection string we used:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/iiop://localhost:7001/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime
```

The method **updateRouteFromXML** in management object route ([see available docu](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/api/management/mbean/ManagedRouteMBean.html#updateRouteFromXml(java.lang.String))) seems to be the right one for this job.

In order to test this method, first **dumpRouteAsXml** is invoked to get a description of the route to modify in XML format.

A sample of the route is depicted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route customId="false" id="route7" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<from uri="servlet:///TESTServer"/>
<convertBodyTo type="[B" id="convertBodyTo7"/>
<removeHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="removeHeader7"/>
  <multicast parallelProcessing="true" timeout="3000" id="multicast7">
    <to uri="http://ip1:8007/IOCServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to19"/>
    <to uri="http://ip2:8007/IOCServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to20"/>
    <to uri="http://ip3:8007/IOCServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to21"/>
  </multicast>
</route>
```

This xml is used as input for the **updateRouteFromXML**:

```
<route customId="false" id="route7" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<from uri="servlet:///TESTServer"/>
<convertBodyTo type="[B" id="convertBodyTo7"/>
<removeHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="removeHeader7"/>
  <multicast parallelProcessing="true" timeout="3000" id="multicast7">
    <to uri="http://ip1:8007/IOCServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to19"/>
    <to uri="http://ip2:8007/IOCServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to20"/>
    <to uri="http://ip3:8007/IOCServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to21"/>
  </multicast>
</route>
```

We have tried several variants (for instance without xml header).

But always get the same exception:

In Jconsole

```
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: CORBA BAD_PARAM 0 No; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at weblogic.iiop.Utils.wrapMARSHALWithCause(Utils.java:906)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.read_value(IIOPInputStream.java:2142)
    at weblogic.iiop.ReplyMessage.getThrowable(ReplyMessage.java:345)
    at weblogic.iiop.InboundResponseImpl.getThrowable(InboundResponseImpl.java:70)
    at weblogic.iiop.InboundResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(InboundResponseImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPRemoteRef.invokeInternal(IIOPRemoteRef.java:232)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPRemoteRef.invoke(IIOPRemoteRef.java:161)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnection_IIOP_WLStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:993)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.inspector.XMBean.invoke(XMBean.java:76)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.inspector.XOperations$1.doInBackground(XOperations.java:151)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA BAD_PARAM 0 No; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at weblogic.iiop.Utils.mapSystemException(Utils.java:941)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.readObject(IIOPInputStream.java:2791)
    at weblogic.utils.io.ObjectStreamClass.readFields(ObjectStreamClass.java:460)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueData(ValueHandlerImpl.java:294)
    at weblogic.corba.utils.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.read_value(IIOPInputStream.java:2128)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.postInvoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:477)
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.invoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:384)
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.invoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:341)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:457)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseStub.meta(_CodeBaseStub.java:105)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.getOrderedDescriptions(IIOPInputStream.java:1281)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.skipObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1635)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleSkipObject(IIOPInputStream.java:465)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:315)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:289)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.read_value(IIOPInputStream.java:2154)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.readObject(IIOPInputStream.java:2788)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at weblogic.iiop.ReplyMessage.getThrowable(ReplyMessage.java:318)
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.postInvoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:468)
    ... 31 more
```

In Weblogic domain log

```
####<04-Mar-2015 09:18:47 o'clock GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <A06687> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogi
c.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <563d78f4cf343dab:1b180373:14be40cba13:-8000-000000000000006d> <14254607271
31> <BEA-080003> <RuntimeException thrown by rmi server: weblogic.corba.cos.codebase.CodeBaseImpl.meta(Ljava.lang.String;)
 org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Could not find FVD class for: RMI:org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:8AC243E89C992A07:000
0000000000001  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No.M
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Could not find FVD class for: RMI:org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:8AC243E89C992A07:0000
000000000001  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: NoM
        at weblogic.corba.cos.codebase.CodeBaseImpl.meta(CodeBaseImpl.java:104)M
        at org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:94)M
        at weblogic.corba.idl.CorbaServerRef.invoke(CorbaServerRef.java:249)M
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)M
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)M
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)M
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)M
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)M
>
```

Has anybody successfully invoked **UpdateRouteFromXml** via JMX?

Same error testing with jdk1.7.0_75

Weblogic domain log

```
####<04-Mar-2015 17:30:22 o'clock GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <A06687>
<AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <563d78f4cf343dab:3d01a2cd:14be5cdcdc4:-8000-0000000000000032> <14254902221 66><BEA-080003> <RuntimeException thrown by rmi server:weblogic.corba.cos.codebase.CodeBaseImpl.meta(Ljava.lang.String;)
 org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Could not find FVD class for: RMI:org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:8AC243E89C992A07:000
0000000000001  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No.M
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Could not find FVD class for: RMI:org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:8AC243E89C992A07:0000
000000000001  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: NoM
        at weblogic.corba.cos.codebase.CodeBaseImpl.meta(CodeBaseImpl.java:104)M
        at org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseImplBase._invoke(_CodeBaseImplBase.java:94)M
        at weblogic.corba.idl.CorbaServerRef.invoke(CorbaServerRef.java:249)M
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:522)M
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)M
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)M
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:518)M
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)M
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)M
>
```

JConsole log

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub stub!
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1845)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:295)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:370)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: 
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2389)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1580)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:414)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:341)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.read_value(IIOPInputStream.java:2154)
    at weblogic.iiop.ReplyMessage.getThrowable(ReplyMessage.java:345)
    at weblogic.iiop.InboundResponseImpl.getThrowable(InboundResponseImpl.java:70)
    at weblogic.iiop.InboundResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(InboundResponseImpl.java:86)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPRemoteRef.invokeInternal(IIOPRemoteRef.java:232)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPRemoteRef.invoke(IIOPRemoteRef.java:161)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnection_IIOP_WLStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1022)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.inspector.XMBean.invoke(XMBean.java:96)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.inspector.XOperations$1.doInBackground(XOperations.java:168)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.postInvoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:477)
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.invoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:384)
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.invoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:341)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:475)
    at com.sun.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseStub.meta(_CodeBaseStub.java:123)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.getOrderedDescriptions(IIOPInputStream.java:1296)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.skipObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1650)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleSkipObject(IIOPInputStream.java:482)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:307)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPInputStream.read_value(IIOPInputStream.java:2154)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:1912)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2335)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at weblogic.iiop.ReplyMessage.getThrowable(ReplyMessage.java:318)
    at weblogic.corba.idl.RemoteDelegateImpl.postInvoke(RemoteDelegateImpl.java:468)
    ... 32 more
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As the WebLogic server was running locally on my laptop I tried a local connection (instead of a remote connection) from JConsole and then retested.
By doing so I got rid of the CORBA error and could see that an exception was being thrown by Camel but it could not be loaded in the client side.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

The complete stacktrace:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Expecting a javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory RMI client socket factory in stub!
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.checkStub(RMIConnector.java:1874)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:295)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.tryConnect(ProxyClient.java:357)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.ProxyClient.connect(ProxyClient.java:313)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.VMPanel$2.run(VMPanel.java:292)
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:246)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.PRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl_Stub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection.invoke(RMIConnector.java:1022)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.inspector.XMBean.invoke(XMBean.java:96)
    at sun.tools.jconsole.inspector.XOperations$1.doInBackground(XOperations.java:168)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:393)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:244)
    ... 12 more
```

I addded to JConsole classpath the camel-core.jar:

```
jconsole -J-Djava.class.path=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\jconsole.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wlfullclient.jar;%WL_HOME%\server\lib\wljmxclient.jar;%M2_HOME%\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-core\2.14.1\camel-core-2.14.1.jar -debug
```

And retested again:

Input XML for testing (in fact it is output from **dumpRouteAsXml**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route customId="false" id="route1" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <from uri="servlet:///TESTServer"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="[B" id="convertBodyTo1"/>
    <removeHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="removeHeader1"/>
    <multicast parallelProcessing="true" timeout="3000" id="multicast1">
        <to uri="http://ip-address1:6001/TARGETServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to1"/>
        <to uri="http://ip-address2:6001/TARGETServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to2"/>
        <to uri="http://ip-address3:6001/TARGETServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to3"/>
    </multicast>
</route>
```

The exception thrown by Camel is now logged and I can see that there is an error in the Route definition. I cannot simple copy the output from **dumpRouteAsXml** and paste it into **updateRouteFromXml**

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [B

Complete stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> ConvertBodyTo[[B] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[servlet:///IOCVodaServer]] -> [ConvertBo... because of [B
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:945)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:805)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2174)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:739)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRouteDefinition(DefaultCamelContext.java:744)
    at org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedRoute.updateRouteFromXml(ManagedRoute.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:244)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1074)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:955)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.invoke(JMXContextInterceptor.java:263)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:444)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.invoke(WLSMBeanServer.java:323)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1427)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:72)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1265)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1360)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:788)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [B
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultClassResolver.resolveMandatoryClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:53)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ConvertBodyDefinition.createProcessor(ConvertBodyDefinition.java:92)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:500)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:213)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:942)
    ... 46 more
```

This "[B" stands for byte[].class. Below you can see the actual configuration, that is set programatically.

```
from("servlet:///TESTServer")
    .convertBodyTo(byte[].class)
    .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
    .multicast()
    .parallelProcessing()
    .timeout(3000)
    .to(eb.getEndpoints("DESTINATIONS1"))
.end();
```

Some trial and error and I got the right XML definition and successfully invoked the **updateRouteFromXml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route customId="false" id="route3" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <from uri="servlet:///TESTServer"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="byte[]" id="convertBodyTo3"/>
    <removeHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="removeHeader3"/>
    <multicast parallelProcessing="true" timeout="3000" id="multicast3">
        <to uri="http://ip-address1:9993/TARGETServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to7"/>
        <to uri="http://ip-address2:9993/TARGETServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to8"/>
        <to uri="http://ip-address3:9993/TARGETServer?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnError=false" id="to9"/>
    </multicast>
</route>
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Java 6 is not supported from Apache Camel 2.14 onwards. You need to use Java 7 or 8.

See the bottom of the release notes:

- http://camel.apache.org/camel-2140-release.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tested with jdk1.7.0_75 and got same error. In the weblogic domain log  ####<04-Mar-2015 17:30:22 o'clock GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <A06687> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogi
c.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <563d78f4cf343dab:3d01a2cd:14be5cdcdc4:-8000-0000000000000032> <14254902221
66> <BEA-080003> <RuntimeException thrown by rmi server: weblogic.corba.cos.codebase.CodeBaseImpl.meta(Ljava.lang.String;)
 org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: Could not find FVD class for....